# Problemas com phpMyAdmin UolHost

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

possuo um site na uol host e um banco de dados também, o site se comunica perfeitamente com o mySql, porém possuo um software desktop que preciso que se comunique com o mySql também, existe alguma configuração que preciso ajustar para que o mySql permita este software desktop se conectar com ele? pois não estou conseguindo fazer esta comunicação. Se alguém puder ajudar agradeço.

Comment: Na hostinger você tem que habilitar a conexão fora do localhost, veja se no seu provedor também tem essa configuração.

Comment: Como é feito isto no hostinger? no próprio phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que a UOL Host deve liberar o acesso remoto (se eles permite isso) para você no seu usuário, se você tem acesso com privilégios necessários, você pode definir o acesso remoto executando o seguinte SQL:

GRANT ALL ON *.* TO meuuser@'SEUIP' IDENTIFIED By 'senha';

Liberando para qualquer ip acessar o banco com senha usando % (não recomendado)

GRANT ALL ON *.* TO meuuser@'%' IDENTIFIED By 'senha';

No arquivo de config do mysql deve permitir acesso ao ip "público" algo como:

/etc/mysql/my.cnf

bind-address = 0.0.0.0

Acredito que sua hospedagem for compartilhada deve a UOL Host liberar o acesso remoto (se for permitido), caso seja você o administrador do banco, deve efetuar as configurações acima.

Comment: Consegui, obrigado.